# Making carousel slider fill the entire page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I made this carousel slide and I wanna make it fill my entire page by changing my CSS code, how would I do that??

This is my Javascript

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');

const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

nextBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    if (counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', ()=>{
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone'){
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - 2; 
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }
    if (carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone'){
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter; 
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';
    }
});
```

and my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" 
    integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <title>My Goals</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel-container">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" id="nextBtn"></i>

        <div class="carousel-slide">
            <img src="img5.jpg" id="lastClone" class="image" alt="">
            <img src="img1.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="img2.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="img3.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="img4.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="img5.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="img1.jpg" id="firstClone" class="image" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and lastly my css (where the "error" is):

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 800px;
}

.carousel-container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-slide {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
}

#prevBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nextBtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 5%;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I have tried to play around with the width: 100% or vh different places in my css but i cant seem to make it work. Remember there is no issue with the code. All i want is to make it 100% on the width and 100% height but when try to do that then the images just look weird and doesn't fill the entire screen like its supposed to. My code pen is here if you wanna help. :)

https://codepen.io/lucasthorsen/pen/gOxYEWm

Comment: use `.image {width: 100%;object-fit: cover;}`

Comment: Doesn't work. if it works for you can you please make a codepen and show me using my js and html code?

Comment: unclear.. do you mean 100% width/height of the page? if so why have you put 1000px on it?

Comment: yes i mean it should fill my entire screen aka 100% height and width. but changing the image class alone doesn't help. the carousel-container's width is set to 1000px and my screen is wider than 1000px so the first step would be to set that to 100%. Try to go on my code pen and see if .image width: 100% and object fit to cover if that fills the entire page/ screen so there is no "white spots" (PS. sorry i know im a noob)

Comment: https://codepen.io/lcherone/pen/YzxKbrM

Comment: Thank you bro, i just made some minor changes like overflow hidden inside the container and min width to just width and the height of .image to 100vh and now it fixed thank you bro you moved me in the right direction

Comment: np, see change I just did to pull up the image if height is small, `object-position: center center;transform: translateY(-50%);`, you might want to add a recalculate of `const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;` on window resize else it borks out